# calc() fallback script

Tags: javascript, beginner, css

I wrote a failback for the fairly new CSS `calc()` rule. It works fine but I want to use it in a production environment and would appreciate feedback.  Please recommend anything regarding weird/wrong code, possible optimizations, or a way to reduce code size.

```
// CSS calc() replacement
function calcfailback(){
   var d = document.createElement('div');
   var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
   _body.appendChild(d);
   d.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   d.style.width = "-webkit-calc(10px)";
   d.style.width = "-o-calc(10px)";  
   d.style.width = "-moz-calc(10px)"; 
   d.style.width = "calc(10px)";   
   var newwidth = d.offsetWidth;
   if (newwidth == "10"){}
   else{
      function resize(){
         document.getElementById('content').style.height = window.innerHeight - 40 + 'px';
         document.getElementById('content').style.width = window.innerWidth - 300 +'px';
         document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = window.innerHeight - 40 + 'px';
      };
      resize();
      window.onresize = function (){
         resize();
      }
   };
   _body.removeChild(d)
};
window.onload = calcfailback;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not very familiar with CSS, but I have a few comments on strictly the JS related parts:

---

**calcfailback**

I would call this `calcFailback` or `calc_failback`.

---

**one var statement**

It's fairly standard practice to only have 1 var statement per scope.  This is because JS does hoisting where it essentially pulls all variable declarations to the top of a scope anyway.

```
function f() {
    var x = 5;
    if (x == 5) {
        var y = 10;
    }
}
```

Is actually silently equivalent to:

```
function f() {
    var x = 5;
    var y;
    if (x == 5) {
        y = 10;
    }
}
```

For this reason (or more particuarly, the odd bugs this can lead to if you forget that it's silently interpretted as this), it's a fairly widespread practice to only use 1 var declaration per scope:

```
function f() {
    var x = 5,
        y;
    ...
}
```

---

**There's no point in a no-op branch**

```
if (newwidth == "10") {}
```

That's fairly pointless.  There are some border situations where having an empty branch can be useful, but for a trivial one like this, just do:

```
if (newwidth != "10") { ... }
```

---

**Variable naming**

I would use either underscores or camelCase so that there's some kind of visual separation of words.  `new_width` and `newWidth` are much easier to read and understand than `newwidth`.

---

**Functions that call other functions are usually pointless**

```
var x = function () { f(); };
```

All this does is create a function bound to `x` that when called, calls `f`.

Unless you specifically want to do this to hide the calling context, it's usually better to just write it as:

```
var x = f;
```

In this situation, `x()` still calls `f`, it just does it without the layer of indirection.

On a technical note though, these are different.  A function without a context defaults to the `window` object as the context (or `undefined` in strict mode).

This means that `this` inside of f may be different depending on how `x` is called.

For example:

```
function f() {
    console.log(this);
}
var x = function() { f(); },
    obj = {foo: "bar"};

x.call(obj); //The console.log will output either window or undefined depending on strict mode
//('this' inside of the wrapper function, however, would be obj)
```

Compared to:

```
function f() {
    console.log(this);
}
var x = f,
    obj = {foo: "bar"};

x.call(obj); //The console.log will output obj (in other words, 'this' inside of 'f' would be 'obj'
```

---

**Your script clobbers any other scripts**

When you assign the `window.onload` and `window.onresize` properties, you may be over writing old handlers.

"But this is the only script on my page!" You say.

Well, it's the only script *for now*.

For the sake of avoiding odd future bugs, I might make a simple little function to stack binding instead:

```
function bindEvt(target, evt, func) {
    var prev = target[evt];
    if (typeof prev !== "function") {
        target[evt] = func;
    } else {
        target[evt] = function() {
            prev.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
            func.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        };
    }
    return target[evt];
}
```

It would be used like:

```
function f() { ... };
bindEvt(window, "onresize", f);
```

(Note: this really should be used as an idea than an actual implementation.  I'm entirely sure that there's at least one major problem with this function.)

---

**Suggested implementation**

I might write it something like this:

```
// CSS calc() replacement
function calcFailback(){
    var d = document.createElement('div'),
        _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        newWidth;

    //functions are actually hoisted too, though in a silenty different way
    function resize() {
        document.getElementById('content').style.height = window.innerHeight - 40 + 'px';
        document.getElementById('content').style.width = window.innerWidth - 300 +'px';
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = window.innerHeight - 40 + 'px';
    }; //You will not usuaully see a ; here.  There's nothing wrong with it though.

    _body.appendChild(d);

    d.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    d.style.width = "-webkit-calc(10px)";
    d.style.width = "-o-calc(10px)";  
    d.style.width = "-moz-calc(10px)"; 
    d.style.width = "calc(10px)";   

    newWidth = d.offsetWidth;

    if (newWidth != "10") { //I might use either !== "10" or !== 10 if you know the type

        resize();
        window.onresize = resize;

        //I might consider inlining the function defition since it's a simple function.
        //You could use a structure like:
        //window.onresize = function() { ... };
        //window.onresize();
        //This is not the same thing as a legitimate onresize event happening though, so you'd need to be
        //careful to make sure that your handler is capable of handling fake events like this.
        //A bit more 'authentic' way might be:
        //window.onresize.call(window); since the handler is probably (I'm not sure) called with window as the context
        //This would still neglect the parameters though.

    } //There was no reason for the ; here

    _body.removeChild(d); //This should have a ; here (mainly for styling purposes in this context, but it's a good habit for situations where it does matter)

}
```

---

**Edit**

For what it's worth, here's a (very) crude example of using a bindEvt like function:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcKPD/1/).

Comment: Amazing post! implemented everything :). Learned a lot about basic code structuring and although the code of the bindEvt itself goes over my head I understand its principle. How would you suggest the bindEvt function could be improved? As you made it it seems to run quite well :).

Comment: @SnippetSpace It's not so much that I know there's a problem with it; it's just that I don't trust my DOM related JS skills very much :).  In fact, this seems to be a better approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411055/javascript-multiple-event-listeners-handlers-on-the-same-element.  That has the browser handle the multiple events instead of creating wrappers over and over again.

Comment: Here is the final code :) http://pastebin.com/Bdp7rbUa

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be a good idea to generalize your code so you can use it with different values. I'm not suggesting you support the full `calc()` syntax, but making it configurable at least could be useful if you plan on using it in more than one place.

For the code you have though, I just have a couple suggestions:

1. I typically avoid underscores in variable names, but that's just a preference (although one that a lot of style guides I've seen share).
2. Replace `if (newwidth == "10"){} else` with `if (newwidth !== 10) {`. Instead of doing nothing in the true case, switch the comparison and skip the else. You can also compare directly with the *number* 10 (using the strict equality operator) instead of doing a string comparison.
3. Function declarations are technically not legal inside `if` statements in ECMAScript (they are only allowed at the global scope, or the top level of a function). Browsers tend to support it as an extension, but they behave differently and it can cause problems, so it's best to avoid that. Function expressions are fine, so I assigned an anonymous function directly to `window.onresize` and called it through that. You could also assign the function to a variable (replace `function resize() {...}` with `var resize = function() {...};`).
4. Instead of calling `document.getElementById('content')` three times, store the style object in a variable and reference that. You'll gain a speed and file-size advantage.
5. Semicolons aren't needed after function declarations or after an `if` statement block.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
// CSS calc() replacement
function calcfailback() {
    var d = document.createElement('div');

    // 1
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(d);
    d.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    d.style.width = "-webkit-calc(10px)";
    d.style.width = "-o-calc(10px)";  
    d.style.width = "-moz-calc(10px)"; 
    d.style.width = "calc(10px)";   
    var newwidth = d.offsetWidth;

    // 2
    if (newwidth !== 10) {
        // 3
        window.onresize = function() {
            // 4
            var contentStyle = document.getElementById('content').style;
            contentStyle.height = window.innerHeight - 40 + 'px';
            contentStyle.width = window.innerWidth - 300 +'px';
            contentStyle.height = window.innerHeight - 40 + 'px';
        };
        window.onresize();
    } // 5
    body.removeChild(d);
} // 5
window.onload = calcfailback;
```

Comment: Thanks for the |var xxx = function| tip. I didn't know it was not "allowed" to use functions directly. :).

Comment: @SnippetSpace Actually, I should clarify that (I left out some words when I was editing that sentence). Function declarations are only legal in the global scope, or directly inside another function. In other words, not inside `if`, `while`, etc. blocks.

Comment: Here is the final code :) http://pastebin.com/Bdp7rbUa

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to check for the `-o-` prefix.  Opera under the Presto engine never had support for `calc()`, prefixed or otherwise.  Opera under the Blink engine supports it without prefixes.